# Can I create a zoomed-in rectangle between two separate tikzpictures without the spy-function (<-- actually, same function, different contents)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to have the smaller rectangle on the right put as the magnifypoint.

Explanation:

- The magnified part on the right essentially shows a magnification of the contents on the left, except not quite.
- It's the same object, just a different photo (taken by myself) from another angle with another position of the camera. Thus, it's a new piece of content that I'd like to have displayed.

So I need something to draw the fancy rectangles/or whatever shape I choose and lines between some, yet unspecified, parts in the left and right tikzpictures. Note: In the end, I'd like to have multiple tikzpictures in the right minipage.

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
tikz,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (3,6) node[below left] {Lots.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small, label=above:bla]
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2) node[below left] {Yes.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why not `spy`-function ?

Comment: @percusse Hm, I haven't figured out yet how I could insert a random image in the magnification part instead of actually showing the magnified part of the "spied on" content.

Comment: Ah, now I've read the question again. So essential question then connecting two images on the same page one of which is on the margin, is that close?

Comment: @percusse Yup. But I figured it out, except it's not possible to link between two seperate tikzpicture-environment. This is bad because of the subcaptions I'd like to use. :/ Anyway, this is the command: `\spy [black, width=1cm, height=2cm] on (1,1) in node [right] at (2,-0.5) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{[insert picture file name here]}};`.

Comment: @percusse So what I meant, was, the `spy`-function of course works in principle. But I would like to have the subcaptions for the little magnified graphics on the right, so I can't use the `spy`-function. I still would like to learn of some method to get the `spy`-look though, with the rectangle and lines between the elements.

Comment: Using hyperref you can link to a standalone (separate file) and open a new window to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I understand you want to draw a box somewhere in the left picture and connect it to the right picture like this?

[image: Connected pictures]

You probably won't get away without drawing the `spy`-looking things yourself, but it's easier than you might think. The key is to add the two keys at the right places: `remember picture` shares node names between all pictures that use this key and `overlay` allows you to draw on top of things without worrying about the bounding box of the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe} % for \includegraphics{image}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Use relative coordinates to draw on image. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/12440
\tikzset{relative coordinates/.style={
    shift=(#1.south west),
    x={($(#1.south east)-(#1.south west)$)},
    y={($(#1.north west)-(#1.south west)$)}
}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Xlength}{\pgf@xx} % Give a usable name to the length of the "x unit vector".
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small, remember picture]
\node[inner sep=0] (large image) {\includegraphics[width=0.66\linewidth]{image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (small image 1) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

Some caption for image 1\\[0.5em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (small image 2) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

Some caption for image 2\\[0.5em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, relative coordinates=large image]
    \node[circle,draw,inner sep=0, minimum size=0.11\Xlength] at (0.51,0.49) {}
        edge (small image 1.west);
    \node[draw,inner sep=0, minimum size=0.05\Xlength] at (0.72,0.44) {}
        edge (small image 2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

As a bonus feature, the markers even scale when the larger picture is resized. ;-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the document with the small image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}% for image
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\medskip\noindent%
\href[pdfnewwindow=true]{target.pdf}{\includegraphics[width=1in]{image}}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The following was used to create target.pdf

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}% for image
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftoolbar=false,pdfwindowui=false,pdfpagemode=UseNone,pdffitwindow=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\includegraphics{image}\\[.25in]
I thought I would add some text here.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Now if I could just figure out how to avoid having to hit the "Restore Down" button.